# If Cylic subgroup implies abelian implies normal then how A5 is simple group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

I am facing problem $A_5$ is simple group, but $A_5$ had 10 cyclic subgroup of order 3, from cyclic $\Rightarrow$ abelian $\Rightarrow$ normal we can say $A_5$ has 10 normal subgroups, but $A_5$ is normal

Help me with this doubt

Comment: These implications are baffling.  Certainly any cyclic group is abelian.  But there are plenty of nonabelian groups with abelian normal subgroups, for instance $S_3$.  Also, $A_5$ has no normal subgroups (because $A_5$ is simple).

Comment: Why abelian subgroup  imply normal subgroup? Consider $S_3$ and a subgroup of order $2$ and suppose generated by a $2 $cycle , then it is abelian but not normal in $S_3$ . The correct statement will be every subgroup of a abelian group is normal subgroup of that group.

Comment: I guess the implication should say: in an abelian group, every subgroup is normal.

Comment: The conclusion "abelian $\Rightarrow$ normal" for subgroups is simply not true.

Comment: I think you have confused "every subgroup **of an** abelian group is normal" (which is true) with "every **abelian subgroup** is normal" (which is false).

Comment: Thank you so much to all of you, for make me clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cyclic group is abelian, and in an abelian group, every subgroup is normal.

However, the abelianness of the subgroup itself says relatively little about its normality. A subgroup being abelian only says something about how the elements of the subgroup interact with one another. A subgroup being normal says something about how the elements of the subgroup interact with the rest of the elements of the (super)group.

There are plenty of abelian subgroups that aren't normal. For instance, the subgroup generated by a 2-cycle in $S_3$. Or, as you found, the 10 subgroups generated by 3-cycles in $A_5$.